# Android VideoView - How to play videos in sequence

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I'm trying to develop an android application that plays more than one video in one videoview. When one is finished, the second has to start and so on.

My videos are stored in the raw folder of the project,
to get their filenames i do:

```
Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();

        final List<String> videoNames = new ArrayList<String>() ;

        for(Field field: fields){
            videoNames.add(field.getName());
        }
```

then i set the first one's path to my video view

```
 videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" 
                            + videoNames.get(0));

myVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
```

to play the others

```
    myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new   MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {


                 videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" 
                            + videoNames.get(VideoI));
                 myVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

                 myVideoView.start();

                 if(VideoI==videoNames.size()-1)
                 {
                     VideoI=0;
                 }
                 else{
                     VideoI++;
                 }
            }
        });
```

BUT...

every time that i try this code in real device, i get the same error 
"can't play video" when the first video is finished...

all the videos are .mp4 file recorded with the same device that i use for develop...

any ideas? or other ways to play more videos in sequence? 
I looked for a solution everywhere but i couldn't find it..

**EDIT**

DID IT!! ok.. the error was so silly.. thank you all for the helpful answers.

the error was in the path i was looking for ("these are not the paths your looking for" cit.)

as i wrote, the videos are stored in raw folder..
i was using

```
 videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + MainActivity.ctx.getPackageName() + "/
                                    + videoNames.get(VideoI));
```

adding raw folder in path

```
videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + MainActivity.ctx.getPackageName() + "/raw/" 
                                    + videoNames.get(VideoI));
```

it finally worked.. as i wrote.. it was a silly..

Comment: kindly can u provide me that sample video code,i need that code into my app,thanks

Comment: MainActivity.ctx.getPackageName()  what is ctx?

Comment: videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + MainActivity.ctx.getPackageName() + "/raw/" 
                                    + videoNames.get(VideoI));          what is "VideoI" kindly explain,thanks

Comment: how can i send you a pm? ctx is the context. check the edited question, i hope it can help you.

Comment: bro not worked for me..me facing crash report..

Comment: videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + MainActivity.ctx.getPackageName() + "/raw/" 
                                    + videoNames.get(VideoI));   at that point my app will crash..i think that crash rise on the "VideoI" issue,can u please update the code that how u can declared "VideoI" variable in your app,please help, me stuck on this issue from yesterday..thanks

Comment: farhanshah1987@gmail.com, if u send me the video code it will be much much appreciated..

Comment: VideoI is an integer, it starts from 1 (int VideoI=1) and every time a video finishes code increments VideoI. When the last video is  finished, VideoI returns to 0 and the first video restart(and so on). VideoI is used to get the correct item in the VideoNames array. VideoNames array contains all the paths of the videos that i want to play in my video view.

Comment: Thanks Alot bro it's work finally..Bundle of thanks for posting ur question :)

Comment: i'm glad you did it :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you are getting error because you are trying to initialize videoview again before reseting it. Make a change to your code like this.

```
myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new   MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            startOtherVid();
        }
});
```

Now make method `startOtherVid()` and initialize videoview here after releasing the previous one.

```
private void startOtherVid(){
  myVideoView.stopPlayback();
  videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" 
                        + videoNames.get(VideoI));
  myVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

  myVideoView.start();
  .... 
   .....
}
```

This way you will release one videoview object and create again. There will be a short time to load, but you can handle it visually.

**Edit**

You can also release mediaplayer object and solve your problem.

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

try {
    mp.reset();
    videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" 
                        + videoNames.get(VideoI));
    myVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

    myVideoView.start();
}
catch(Exception e){e.printstacktrace();}
});
```

Cheers.:)

Comment: i added miVideoview.stopPlayback(); line but i have the same issue. by the way Logcat give me this error MediaPlayer(2943): Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: Ok i tried your solution and also the @Rajan 's one.. i'm still facing the issue..looking at logcat messages i found "Can't open file on client side, trying on server side" and "path is null" errors..i'm looking for the first one, the second is weird because all the videos path are not null...

Comment: So are you getting previous error `MediaPlayer(2943): Error (1,-2147483648)` ? If not; then the previous problem is solved and now you are having problem while getting filename.

Comment: check the edit question.. i solved setting the correct path! thank you for your help.. i'm gonna choose this one as correct answer for the mp.reset() advise ;)

Comment: @Jay videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" 
                        + videoNames.get(VideoI));    kindly explain that what is "VideoI",Thanks

Comment: and also MainActivity.ctx.getPackageName() what is ctx?

Comment: @FarhanShah, I just answered based on OP, where `these didnt matter` to resolve problem. Kindly wait for OP to answer you !

Comment: @FarhanShah VideoI is an int, every time a video finish, VideoI grows to get the correct video path from String[] VideoNames.

Comment: @FarhanShah ctx is context

Comment: @BlueSword Hey I have taken your answer to add into my answer in (SO in Spanish)[http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31336/videoview-reproducir-varios-videos]!

Comment: @Elenasys, Thanks for letting me know. It is great to reaching out to even more people through our responses. :)

Answer (score 6):

Try something like that - it works perfect for me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private VideoView videoView = null;
String[] videoArray = {"video1", "video2"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + MainActivity.this.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + videoArray[0]);

    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    videoView.start();

    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
        {
            Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + MainActivity.this.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + videoArray[1]);
            videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
            videoView.start();
        }
    });
}
}
```