# Playing video one by one by using cursor

Tags: android, android-cursor

i had been developing android app which will browse the internal storage and display the videos and it should play the video one by one in the list.
But i am stuck at playing videos one by one. it used to scan the list and used to play only last video.

```js
package com.com.videolist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
      private Cursor videocursor;
      private int video_column_index;
      ListView videolist;
      int count;
   
      String name = null;
       VideoView video_player_view;
    DisplayMetrics dm;
    SurfaceView sur_View;
    MediaController media_Controller;
 
       public class MediaFileInfo {

           private String fileName,filePath,fileType;

     this.fileName = fileName;
           }

           public String getFilePath() {
               return filePath;
           }

           public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
               this.filePath = filePath;
           }

           public String getFileType() {
               return fileType;
           }

           public void setFileType(String fileType) {
               this.fileType = fileType;
           }
       }
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            init_phone_video_grid();
      }

      private void init_phone_video_grid() {
            System.gc();
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
         
           videocursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj,null, null, null);
          
            count = videocursor.getCount();
            Log.d("count:", String.valueOf(count));
            videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.VideoList);
            videolist.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
          
            Log.d("No of Video",""+count);



          
          if(videocursor !=null && videocursor.getCount()>0 && videocursor.moveToFirst()) {
              do {
                  for (int i = 0; i < videocursor.getCount(); i++) {

                      Log.d("i", String.valueOf(i));
                      MediaFileInfo mediaFileInfo = new MediaFileInfo();
                      video_column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                      videocursor.moveToPosition(i);
                      // Log.d("getcolumn", String.valueOf(videocursor.moveToPosition(i)));
                     
                      name = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
                      mediaFileInfo.setFileName(name);
                      Log.d("name", name);
                      final int column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                    //  Log.d("column_index", String.valueOf(video_column_index));
                      //    videocursor.moveToPosition(i);

                      final String filepath = videocursor.getString(column_index);
                      //   Log.d("last i", String.valueOf(i));
                      Log.d("filepath", filepath);
                      mediaFileInfo.setFilePath(filepath);
                      video_player_view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
                      media_Controller = new MediaController(this);
                      dm = new DisplayMetrics();
                      this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
                      int height = dm.heightPixels;
                      int width = dm.widthPixels;
                      video_player_view.setMinimumWidth(width);
                      video_player_view.setMinimumHeight(height);

                      video_player_view.setMediaController(media_Controller);
                      // Log.d("last i", String.valueOf(i));
                      Log.d("filepath", filepath);

                      //   if(videocursor != null && videocursor.getCount()>0){

                      //       videocursor.moveToFirst();
                      //       do{
                      //        for(i=0;i<videocursor.getCount();i++){




                          video_player_view.setVideoPath(filepath);
                          //     Log.d("for=last i", String.valueOf(i));
                          //      Log.d("for=filepath", filepath);
                          video_player_view.requestFocus();
                      Log.d("videoview","videoview");
                          video_player_view.start();


                   

                  }

              }

              while (videocursor.moveToNext());
          }
      


      }






      public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context vContext;

                  public VideoAdapter(Context c) {
                        vContext = c;
            }

            public int getCount() {
                  return count;
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                  return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                  return position;
            }
@Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                  System.gc();

                  TextView tv = new TextView(vContext.getApplicationContext());

                  String id = null;
                  if (convertView == null) {
                        video_column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                        videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
                       id = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);


                       tv.setText(id);

                  } else
                        tv = (TextView) convertView;
                 return tv;
            }

      }


}
```

And logcat of that application:

```js
09-15 06:34:40.586 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 0
09-15 06:34:40.587 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: h.264_acc_f4v.f4v
09-15 06:34:40.587 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/h.264_acc_f4v.f4v
09-15 06:34:40.612 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/h.264_acc_f4v.f4v
09-15 06:34:40.614 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.616 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 1
09-15 06:34:40.616 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: H.264_F4v aac codec.f4v
09-15 06:34:40.617 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_F4v aac codec.f4v
09-15 06:34:40.635 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_F4v aac codec.f4v
09-15 06:34:40.636 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.637 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 2
09-15 06:34:40.637 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: H.263_mp3_avi.avi
09-15 06:34:40.637 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.263_mp3_avi.avi
09-15 06:34:40.660 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.263_mp3_avi.avi
09-15 06:34:40.662 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.662 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 3
09-15 06:34:40.663 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: H.264_mp3_flv.flv
09-15 06:34:40.664 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_mp3_flv.flv
09-15 06:34:40.689 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_mp3_flv.flv
09-15 06:34:40.690 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.690 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 4
09-15 06:34:40.691 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: H.264__aac_flv.flv
09-15 06:34:40.691 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264__aac_flv.flv
09-15 06:34:40.710 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264__aac_flv.flv
09-15 06:34:40.711 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.712 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 5
09-15 06:34:40.712 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: H.264_aac_m2ts.m2ts
09-15 06:34:40.712 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_aac_m2ts.m2ts
09-15 06:34:40.729 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_aac_m2ts.m2ts
09-15 06:34:40.730 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.730 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 6
09-15 06:34:40.731 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: H.265_aac_mkv.mkv
09-15 06:34:40.731 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.265_aac_mkv.mkv
09-15 06:34:40.747 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.265_aac_mkv.mkv
09-15 06:34:40.748 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.749 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 7
09-15 06:34:40.750 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: H.264_amr_nb_3GPP_3g2.3g2
09-15 06:34:40.750 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_amr_nb_3GPP_3g2.3g2
09-15 06:34:40.769 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_amr_nb_3GPP_3g2.3g2
09-15 06:34:40.771 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.771 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 8
09-15 06:34:40.772 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: h.265_ac3_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:40.772 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/h.265_ac3_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:40.817 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/h.265_ac3_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:40.819 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.819 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 9
09-15 06:34:40.820 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: mpeg2video_aac_ts.ts
09-15 06:34:40.820 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/mpeg2video_aac_ts.ts
09-15 06:34:40.840 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/mpeg2video_aac_ts.ts
09-15 06:34:40.841 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.842 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 10
09-15 06:34:40.842 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: flv_mp3_flv.flv
09-15 06:34:40.842 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/flv_mp3_flv.flv
09-15 06:34:40.863 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/flv_mp3_flv.flv
09-15 06:34:40.864 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.864 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 11
09-15 06:34:40.865 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: mpeg2video_mp2_mpg.mpg
09-15 06:34:40.865 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/mpeg2video_mp2_mpg.mpg
09-15 06:34:40.870 6539-6612/com.com.videolist W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.HardwareRenderer android.view.View$AttachInfo.mHardwareRenderer' on a null object reference
                                                             at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.dumpGfxInfo(WindowManagerGlobal.java:504)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpGfxInfo(ActivityThread.java:1104)
                                                             at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:560)
                                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
09-15 06:34:40.907 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/mpeg2video_mp2_mpg.mpg
09-15 06:34:40.908 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.908 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 12
09-15 06:34:40.909 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: rawvideo_pcm_s16le_avi.avi
09-15 06:34:40.910 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/rawvideo_pcm_s16le_avi.avi
09-15 06:34:40.932 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/rawvideo_pcm_s16le_avi.avi
09-15 06:34:40.934 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.934 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 13
09-15 06:34:40.934 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: xvid_aac_mpeg4_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:40.935 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/xvid_aac_mpeg4_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:40.958 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/xvid_aac_mpeg4_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:40.959 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.960 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 14
09-15 06:34:40.960 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: MPEG4_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:40.961 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/MPEG4_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:40.975 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/MPEG4_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:40.976 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.976 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 15
09-15 06:34:40.977 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: H.265_aac_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:40.977 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.265_aac_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:40.992 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.265_aac_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:40.993 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:40.994 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 16
09-15 06:34:40.994 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: h.263_amr_nb_3gp.3gp
09-15 06:34:40.994 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/h.263_amr_nb_3gp.3gp
09-15 06:34:41.006 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/h.263_amr_nb_3gp.3gp
09-15 06:34:41.007 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:41.007 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 17
09-15 06:34:41.008 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: H.264_mp3_mkv.mkv
09-15 06:34:41.008 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_mp3_mkv.mkv
09-15 06:34:41.020 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_mp3_mkv.mkv
09-15 06:34:41.021 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:41.022 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 18
09-15 06:34:41.022 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: H.264_aac_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:41.022 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_aac_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:41.035 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_aac_mp4.mp4
09-15 06:34:41.038 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:41.038 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 19
09-15 06:34:41.039 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: H.264_aac_mkv.mkv
09-15 06:34:41.039 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_aac_mkv.mkv
09-15 06:34:41.053 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/H.264_aac_mkv.mkv
09-15 06:34:41.054 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:41.054 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/i: 20
09-15 06:34:41.055 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/name: h264_acc_flv.flv
09-15 06:34:41.055 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/h264_acc_flv.flv
09-15 06:34:41.066 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/filepath: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/h264_acc_flv.flv
09-15 06:34:41.067 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/videoview: videoview
09-15 06:34:41.275 6539-6557/com.com.videolist W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.HardwareRenderer android.view.View$AttachInfo.mHardwareRenderer' on a null object reference
                                                             at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.dumpGfxInfo(WindowManagerGlobal.java:504)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpGfxInfo(ActivityThread.java:1104)
                                                             at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:560)
                                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
09-15 06:34:41.275 6539-6539/com.com.videolist I/Choreographer: Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-15 06:34:41.516 6539-6539/com.com.videolist W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Videos/h264_acc_flv.flv
09-15 06:34:41.763 6539-6539/com.com.videolist D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
09-15 06:34:41.823 6539-6556/com.com.videolist W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (3, 0)
09-15 06:34:43.241 6539-6552/com.com.videolist W/CursorWrapperInner: Cursor finalized without prior close()
```

Comment: yes, because of Loop will iterate on entire list and reach at last.

Comment: i want to play the video one by one from starting of the list. how can i do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549700/android-videoview-how-to-play-videos-in-sequence

Comment: You required particular listener on completion.

Comment: by placing the listener. i was able to loop only one particular video.

Comment: You should do something is your for loop like: while(myVideo.isPlaying()) so that the for loop only iterates once the actual video is finished

Comment: by using while(video_player_view.isPlaying()) also it was able to play only one video. it was not playing one by one