# Android: How to play videos smoothly in sequence without glitch and delay?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-videoview, video-processing

I need to show videos one after one Just like in [CLIPS](https://www.apple.com/in/clips/) app of Apple. I have followed these approaches -

- Like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21549700/5996106), I have given next video path to `VideoView` in its `onCompleteListener', but I am facing a very little delay as`VideoView` takes time to prepare and start, delay is very little, but I need very smooth transition from one video to another.
- I also used two `VideoView`s and when the first video is being played, other 
  `VideoView` is initialized and prepared already and I call `videoView2`.start()`in`onCompleteListener' of the first `VideoView` . Here In this case, Both VideoViews are in `RelativeLayout` of same sizes and same position ,Second VideoView is given `height=0` & `width=0` while first one is previewing and vice-verca. This is also little glitchy not that smooth.

Actually I am using VideoView to show **Preview** of Videos which later on I have to **Merge**. So, I need to show exact preview how it will look like after merging like in video editing apps.

Also `VideoView` don't support animations otherwise I was thinking of giving `alpha` animation between two videoviews so that user won't see that glitchiness when switching videoviews

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of delay you can use 2 VideoViews. Play video in 1st view and when it load video in other video while it is invisible , then when progress of 1st VideoView reaches above 99% then hide it and show the 2nd one and keep repeating the procedure for all videos. Otherwise delay will remain there, i faced same issue as well.

Comment: Already tried this, see my question . Also VideoView doesnt went GONE on setting visibility

Comment: place videoView in any other view and apply visibility to that parent. It would work for sure.

Comment: well, xml is too long , but video part is simple a relative layout with match parentwidth and custom height and a videoview inside it with match parent height and width , same for other.